# Shin Godzilla/ シン・ゴジラ/ Shin Gojira/ Godzilla: Resurgence

Tags: translation

What does シン mean in シン・ゴジラ? My dictionary says "thin."

Online comments imply that it "could mean true, new, God, shaking, and so on." That's a long stretch away.

I assume that 'shin gojira' is just a phonetic variation and that 'Godzilla: Resurgence' a creative translation (for commercial purposes, to differentiate it from all the other Godzilla movies).

Answer (score 4):

Since シン is written in katakana, the meaning is not very clear even to a native speaker who sees this title. Under the hood, this シン has multiple meanings by intention. According to [this article](https://www.sponichi.co.jp/entertainment/news/2015/09/23/kiji/K20150923011187800.html):

> タイトルは庵野秀明総監督（５５）が「新」「真」「神」などさまざまな意味を込めて命名。
>
> Director Hideaki Anno gave the title due to the variety of meanings シン conveys, such as "new" (新), "true" (真), and "God" (神).

新 and 真 are both common prefixes for a sequel. The meaning of "shaking" is probably 震. Some may recall English "sin", too, but I don't know how "thin" relates to Godzilla.